# When I go back from browser to the SO post then SO post is not coming as updated

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, caching

There is a bug in SO posts that suppose I am reading a SO post which also contain a link to other website and then after I upvoted/downvoted it and then when I click on that link and go back from my browser then it show me the post not upvoted/downvoted. So because of which I click again on upvote/downvote which is very annoying.

Can you guys please change this behaviour I have faced this issue several times.

Comment: It's likely just caching. Refresh the post and you'll see your vote.

Comment: But I think it should not happen. It is happening everytime for every post.

Comment: Show me ANY website where you can do an update, leave the page, go back (with a brower "back", not revisit the page ofc), and see your change..... this is just.... not how caching and browsers work.....

Comment: Can you please have a relook at my question @Patrice

Comment: Visited links are handled differently by the browser, which has nothing to do with the page loading or the scripts therein.

Comment: @TinyGiant Then why SO developers don't do the same thing then ??

Comment: I suppose click again will reverse your vote.

Comment: @SudhanshuGaur Because the SO team cannot control what browsers do. They're developed by entirely separate teams of people.

Comment: @TGrif sorry but i don't get you ?? as if i have upvoted my post and tehn when i move back it should show me that i have updated the post ?? Is there anything wrong in that functionality ??

Comment: @SudhanshuGaur If you want to write your own browser that always reloads pages when using the back button, more power to you.  SO is in the business of making QA sites, not building browsers, and so isn't going to make their own browser with different functionality than whatever your browser does to fix this for you.

Comment: @DavisBroda then how in case for google search it is happening correctly ?? Look if this functionality only work becuase of browser side then on every website when i click on the link and then when i come back again then that link should be highlightened ??

Comment: Your up or down vote is posted as an ajax request. Your vote never becomes part of the document as stored in the history of your browser. Your votes are not fetched when the page is served from the browser cache. To see your votes you have to do a reload so the server can serve you a page that has your vote in it. To resolve this minor issue a lot of dev time / re-design is needed and possible performance will be lost.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. If you have questions about how the google website works, go and ask google.

Comment: @rene they can store it in browser storage and then when page is being rendered then they can see whether user upvoted post previously or not ?? Thanks for answering.

Comment: Sure, they can do all kind of things. Instead they build Documentation, Team, Jobs and Channels. Tough choices.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ `If you have questions about how the google website works, go and ask google` Sorry if i got you wrong but in comments other users asked me to mention any other website where this functionalty doesn't work. That's why I pointed out this issue. Please read before doing anything.

Comment: [You already asked once in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357713/when-i-go-back-from-browser-to-the-so-post-then-so-post-is-not-coming-as-updated?noredirect=1#comment521781_357713). Just be patient and wait, don't vandalise your question.

Comment: Google - and other sites - remember which links you've clicked on because those links are stored in your internet history. If it sees a page in your recent history that matches the link it colors it in. However your voting information is not kept in your browsing history, so the browser has no way of knowing the action has taken place, and renders the page as it was last loaded; without any votes.

Comment: @DavisBroda But can't they store it in browser storage and then when page is being rendered then they can see whether user upvoted post previously or not ??

Comment: No, that would be immensely complex, you need to keep track which questions you visited, what their vote state was, then onload determine which value is true, the server one, or the localstorage one. Now bring in that you can undo your vote in a second tab or even in another browser. Or from your phone, or from your work pc. And then you navigate back to a page from 3 weeks ago. What do you expect to happen? I would personally just want to reload the frigging page from the server so that I know I'm looking at up to date and valid for all data.

Comment: @rene Look when i have undo my question from different tab still it work as storage is again the same where upvoted posts are stored so now it would be removed. Also what user is going to do in other browser upvote/downvote/undo for all the cases my answer will be compromised but the current code which SO is using is also compromised. because both codes are not working for this case but atleast for the case where user upvote/downvote from sametab or from different tab my answer will work.

Comment: you mention "your answer", but you don't have an answer. You have - at best - a vague idea of an end-goal, but no plausible means to get there, or for dealing with anything but the most absolutely straightforward of cases. Maybe this would be better received if you had a specific idea of how this is to be accomplished, but as it stands you're asking SO to put in a ton of work essentially rewriting incoming browser's caching functionality for what is at best marginal improvement to the end-user, as they can just reload the page for the same result.

Comment: I've been using the site for 7 years now and cast some 23,000 votes. I've run into this from time to time but somehow it's not been a problem, ever, not even a single time. If you care about the vote count then reload the page. Problem solved. No?

Comment: If your scenario is also only half a fix then let just keep the status quo and do nothing. The only thing that could work is make an extra roundtrip to the server on pageloadComplete, either via an ajax call or a websocket to fetch the actual voting state. But as I said earlier, Nick is going to hate you for the extra connections/network/server load that will cost. And if the solution is going to comprise average pagespeed for everyone you can forget it. It will be a [tag:status-declined]

Comment: @sudhanshuGaur hmmmm..... you clicking on a link and your browser highlighting it in blue isn't you pushing an update to Google's site. This is all browser side. Not like you updating the score of an answer on Google....

Comment: @rene yes but partial is better then nothing.

Comment: @Patrice yes i am pushing update to google but same is the case for SO there ?? don't you think ??

Comment: No, you are NOT pushing an update to Google. I may have been unclear. But the "link has been visited by you" isn't kept by Google, but by your browser. That's the difference here.

Comment: Sorry... what? The visited link functionality (i.e. your browser highlighting links that you have visited) is entirely on the browser end. That has absolutely nothing to do with the website the links are contained on. Similarly, if you click on a link here, then press the back button, that link will be marked as visited and highlighted as such. This happens no matter where you are on the web because it is controlled by the browser, and has absolutely nothing to do with the site you're viewing.

Comment: @TinyGiant I clicked on a link on a facebook post and then that link didn't get highlightened ??

Comment: It is possible using CSS to disable visited link highlighting. Facebook may be doing that. That has nothing to do with refreshing the page on press of the back button. They would only be changing the color of the  visited links to that of normal links. I don't ever use or visit Facebook, so I don't know what for sure they are doing.

Comment: And even if you would rely on the [`:visited`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited) state of a link and use that on the votes button, there is no way to unvisit a link, so if you undo your vote it would still remain visited.

Comment: Facebook **is not** a good reference on what browsing should be. I have to write custom stuff to query their API to get a decent browsing experience...

Comment: @rene yes you are right but that's why i suggested to use browser storage.

Comment: It's a little annoying that I cannot answer this, but I think this question was shot down a bit early. It **is** technically possible to do what OP suggests, in modern browsers. Use the [history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History), and update the page when it is revisited. From where? Well, from [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage), for example. Whether or not SO wants to do that is a different question, but the critique of 'this is how browsers work' is not valid, IMHO.

Comment: This is completely possible. It just requires SO to rip out all ajax calls, remove all live notification of activity, and require that any user interaction with the website triggers a postback to the server with an accompanying reload of the entire webpage.  You cool with that?  Or with having all the benefits of async http requests while dealing with some browser caching issues?

Answer (score 20):

This is just how browsers work.  SO has no say in this.  Your browser is re-building the page based on its own memory of what the page was like the last time it loaded it, rather than fetching it from SO again.

Comment: Can you please have a relook at my question. Thanks for answering here.

Comment: Yet, it is possible to run some custom code when a page is revisited. See [history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History) and my other, slightly more elaborate, [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357713/when-i-go-back-from-browser-to-the-so-post-then-so-post-is-not-coming-as-updated#comment521990_357713).